# Input add text on line before input

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

The code below asks for your name, takes the input, and then displays your name.

### Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    System.out.println("What is your name?");
    Scanner name = new Scanner(System.in); //Passed in "Vincent"
    System.out.println("Hello, " + name.nextLine() + "!");
}
```

### Output:

What is your name?

Vincent

Hello, Vincent!

### Question:

How would I combine the first two lines, so that I can have something similar to:

"What is your name: namehere"

Comment: Don't use `println` but `print`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `println` which adds the **new line** character at the end of your string.

Use this instead:

```
System.out.print("What is your name? ");
```

[Read more here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html).

Comment: Thanks! The article was helpful as well, I'll be sure to start checking the documentation before asking a stupid question again lol.

Answer (score 0):

Just change `println` to `print` so the newline is not printed.

```
System.out.print("What is your name: ");
```